Render HTML in calculated column
After Microsoft stopped allowing HTML to render in calculated columns, I applied the below script to my web part page. However, it doesn't work if I page over in the view (ie. I go from 1-30, 31-60). What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var text = $(".ms-vb2:contains('<div')";
      text.each(function() {
      var html = $(this).html();
      $(this).html(html);
      });
  });
</script>


Are you using classic experience list view page to add this custom JavaScript?

Yes. I have the view on a web part page. I'm then using a content editor web part to link to the .js file.
